# Delete a Calculation View which is open in transport

Tags: view, hana, calculation

Our team developed 15 calculation views in HANA and all the views are activated and present in a Open Transport change list.

If I want to delete one of the views which is not supposed to be transported from the Development System. Is there a way I can delete it from Open Transport ?

Thanks
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

When you say Open Transport, are you referring to the Change ids that are collected in a Rev trac. And the rev track has not been approved/moved to the next landscape.

If so, you would have to recollect the object again, since these are non Abap components that are collected as part of a TGZ file. This is a zipped file that can not be separated.

Thanks,

Kumar Attangudi Perichiappan Perichappan